# How to execute AsyncTask<> located in a fragment from its parent?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

This seems harder than it look or I am doing it wrong. I need to update the content of UI elements in a fragment.

So, within an `Activity`, I start `AsyncTask` task like this

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Inside "normal" `Activity` this async class is `private` so I thought that I could make it `public` inside the fragment class and then be able to call it from `FragmentActivity` parent class. Something like this:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.my_fragment);
new myFragment.DoParsingAsyncTask().execute(""); //??? a silly guess
```

This **did not work**.

Can anyone help?

PS. My fragments are not `<fragment>` views in XML, but I deal with them via `ViewPager`. I have no problem displaying pages via `ViewPager`.
PPS. this async class starts parsing remote content and fill UI elements in the fragment.

Comment: myFragment.new DoParsingAsyncTask().execute(""); ? Also you always can create your task classes as separate classes and use handlers to update UI.

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov I am converting `Activity`-based scheme into fragments and I am trying to find out the simplest solution. This was just a bad guess.

Comment: myFragment.new DoParsingAsyncTask().execute("") works? You need create  inner classes instances by this way.

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov no, it does not work. I don't think the syntax is right.

Comment: Syntax is right. IF your inner class is static to create inner instance you can new OuterClass.InnerClass(), if inner is non static you need outer class instance to create inner instance outer.new InnerClass() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: It might not solve the problem, but create a method in your fragment and call that to create and start the async task.  It will just be tidier.

Comment: @PhilipPearl you may post this as an answer as this helped. I would be glad to accept it. THANKS!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might not solve the problem, but create a method in your fragment and call that to create and start the async task. It will just be tidier. Here is the code.

From `Fragment` call the method like this.

```
Activity myActivity = getActivity();
if (myActivity instanceof MyActivity) {
     ((MyActivity) myActivity).doAsyncTaskMethod();
}
```

Or you can try the solution I've already proposed.

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.my_fragment);
myFragment.new DoParsingAsyncTask().execute("");
```

Which works as well.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wanted to do the reverse (call an async task in the hosting activity from it's fragment), and I couldn't get the syntax right. What I needed was the getActivity().new MyAsyncTask().execute() bit :)